# Why is including . at the back of the PATH on UNIX dangerous?

Tags: security, unix, solaris, solaris-10

May I know what is the security risk if my directory has `:.` at the back of the path? How can I remove it?

Comment: BTW, this would probably be more topical at http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/; it's not really a programming question, which is StackOverflow's domain.

Comment: Having `.:` at the front of `$PATH` is even more dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Including the current working directory in your PATH is dangerous because malicious users or programs can populate shared directories -- such as `/tmp` -- with common typos of regular commands.

This kind of attack used to be very popular in college campuses; typing `sl` instead of `ls` in `/tmp` was a fairly good way to have your account owned.

An easy fix (if you know that it will only be at the end) is to modify your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (as appropriate) to contain a line similar to:

```
PATH=${PATH%:.}
```